# Ajax call controller with Insert query ASP.NET

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tested my update query from my editor and it works fine but if I am going to implement it to my ajax and call the update from my controller the result is failed and it always alert me says "Not Found"

[image]

Here is my Ajax call from my view:

```
function SaveChanges() {
    var Op_dif = document.getElementById("Op_dif").value
    var op = document.getElementById("OP").value        

    //alert(OP + " , " + Op_desc)
    $.ajax({            
        url: '/HomeController/UpdateOP',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'Op_dif': Op_dif,
            'op': op
        },            

        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateOP(int Op_dif, string op)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET Op_dif = @Op_dif WHERE op = @op ", con);
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Op_dif", Op_dif);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op", op);                
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: `url: '/Home/UpdateOP',` and delete `contentType: 'application/json',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should say `Home/UpdateOP` instead of `HomeController/UpdateOP` because that is the routing semantics. Always omit the part controller at the end.

Ajax call should be like this:

```
function SaveChanges() {
    var Op_dif = document.getElementById("Op_dif").value
    var op = document.getElementById("OP").value        

    //alert(OP + " , " + Op_desc)
    $.ajax({            
        url: '/Home/UpdateOP',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'Op_dif': Op_dif,
            'op': op
        },            

        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem you have is that you are returning a `RedirectToAction` at the end of the method which does not make sens in ajax call. Try to return `JsonResult` instead and handle it properly. You can return something like this:

```
return Json({Status = "Ok", Message = "Data updated successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and then in js code success method do something like this.

```
if(data.Status == "Ok") {
   alert(data.Message);
} else {
   alert("Something bad happened");    
}
```

Comment: my controller is in HomeController.cs should I transfer it?

Comment: Dont change anything in your controller. Just change ajax call url to this:  url: '/Home/UpdateOP'

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm getting this pop now 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: Well, that means your problem is solved, the action is found. The internal server error might be caused by many issues, mostly bugs in you code. Set a breakpoint in you code and debug.Check what is the c# code issue inside the action

Comment: do you know what do I need to put in my controller to track my error. like going back to basic just simply print some text to verify if I am reading the right path

Comment: I guess your problem is as described in the comment but in case you want to fully debug what is going on check how to set breakpoints in visual studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017 or just copy paste my code

Comment: I got it working now cool! appreciate both of you, I just put the Home on url and removed contentType: 'application/json' as well

Comment: Do you know how can I refresh my page once I done my update coz on my db table it was successfully updating but in my page it was not. wondering if I can call as well my index page when it return success

Comment: At the success method put `location.reload();`. If this is the correct answer please consider marking it as such. :).